# Simple testing question related to inserting and updating of custom object data and persistence of the data post-test run

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, test-setup

I am new to SF coding and I have a fairly complex Apex class that takes a bunch of data and uses it to generate data into a new custom object. This is not a trigger but meant to be a scheduled batch run that happens once a week. The test runs SEEM to run correctly with no issues but the custom object is still empty post run. I am having trouble understanding the rules around isolation of test data. I am using the SeeAllData=true flag so that, as an input, I can take some real data and consume it. I have setup debug points and I see records being staged for insertion into my custom object with the last line being an insert line. Is there a way to force the system to commit the data in a way that it persists after the test ends? Thanks in advance!

Comment: no. test data will not persist. why do you need it to? As for seealldata and test, you should always create all necessary records to setup the database to be able to perform whatever test you are after.

Comment: If you want the changes to persist, why not just execute the Batch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test classes rollback test data after their execution and this should be the expected behavior.

There can be multiple drawbacks for keeping test data

1. This will hamper production data quality.
2. Test classes are executed each time you deploy to production and it will keep creating the sample data.

Using (seeallData=True), system gives you access to data available in the org, however it roll backs all changes when test execution is done.